# Redirect to previous page if any PHP error occurs

Tags: php, apache

I'd like to know if it is possible with Apache to make a rule that if any PHP error occurs while loading a page, automatically redirect to previous location (while keeping headers/parameters) ?

It would be perfect if this could be done without touching every php file, like just writing it somewhere to make it work.

Thanks for feedbacks

Comment: What do you mean by "PHP error" exactly? A fatal parse error?! (Although that should _never_ occur in a live environment?!) What "headers" (I assume you mean HTTP request headers) would need to be preserved? A "redirect" won't necessarily preserve any headers from the initial request. And what do you mean by "parameters"? URL parameters in the query string?

Comment: If you use rewrite to send all page requests through a single page, then that one controller can handle errors. (Rather, can handle exceptions.)  It’s too lengthy a subject to go into detail here, but you can find tutorials about how to route all traffic through a single script location.